# Mysql SET function doesn't work in VB6 through odbc connector

Tags: mysql, vb6

my webserver is WAMP by phpmyadmin i can use this SQL:

```
SET @pag:=0;
SELECT * FROM (SELECT @pag:=@pag+1 as pagina,id,nome FROM schede2014 order by id) as ris WHERE upper(ris.nome) like upper('ci%')
```

but if i try do same by vb6:

```
AdoTmp.RecordSource = "SELECT @pag:=0; SELECT * FROM (SELECT @pag:=@pag+1 as pagina,id,nome,arrivo,partenza FROM schede2014 order by id) as ris WHERE upper(ris.nome) like upper('" + inutile + "%')"

AdoTmp.LockType = adLockReadOnly
AdoTmp.Refresh
```

at this point i got SYNTAX error in my sql function.
If i remove: SET @pag:=0; it work but without giving me the pagina values, just all NULL
Any solution?

Comment: IIRC, some database connectors block multiple statements in one request by default. You'll need to turn that off, or try executing them individually. What connector are you using?

Comment: i use MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver. i saw in detail of this driver and i tried to check Allow multiple statements but no effects, have lot of other settings but i didnt tried it all.

Comment: i found a round around the problem: SELECT * FROM (SELECT @p:=@p+1 AS pagina, t.id,t.nome,t.arrivo,t.partenza FROM schede2014 t,(SELECT @p:=0) foo ORDER BY id) as loo WHERE upper(loo.nome) like upper('ci%') ORDER BY loo.id in this way the odbc dont give error because is everything on 1 statement. bu i wish to have a solution for the multi statement error, because  for sure i will need in future! TY